# Angular 9 cdk virtual scroll - scroll index is not changing even if user scrolls

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular9, angular-cdk

I am using angular 9 to perform infinite scroll using CdkVirtualScrollViewport. I am calling `(scrolledIndexChange)` to detect index change. As the index changes, I want to load more data from my API's.

But the problem is the index is always zero. Even if the user tries to scroll index value is not changing.

At my API I have two fields- limit and skip. Limit specifies how many records you want to retrieve and skip specifies how much records to be skipped. So skip value is  0  for index `scrolledIndexChange` 0, and skip value is incremented if `scrolledIndexChange` is greater than zero.

But the index is not changing. I also checked that it has not reached the last page

.ts

```
import { CdkVirtualScrollViewport } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';

@ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport) viewport: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;

  constructor(public FactService : FactService) {
    this.get_count()
  }

get_count(){
    this.FactService.getcount().subscribe(data => {
      if(data){
        console.log(data.count)
        this.count = data.count
        this.total_pages = Math.ceil(data.count/this.limit)
        console.log(this.total_pages)
      }
    })
  }

  trackByIdx(i: number) {
    return i;
  }

  getdata(limit, skip){

    this.FactService.getdata(limit, skip).subscribe(data =>{
      if(data){
        console.log(data);
        this.infinite = this.infinite.concat(data)
        }
    })
  }


  index(val) {

    this.page ++ ;
    console.log(val)
    console.log(this.page , this.total_pages)
    if(val == 0) {
      console.log("zero")
     this.getdata(8,0)
    }

    else {

      if(this.page === this.total_pages) {
        console.log("finished")
        return ;
      } 
      else {
        const end = this.viewport.getRenderedRange().end;
        const total = this.viewport.getDataLength();
        console.log(`${end}, '>=', ${total}`);

        console.log("else")

        if(end === total) {

         this.getdata(this.limit, this.skip+8)

        }
      }


    }
```

html

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport  itemSize="100" (scrolledIndexChange)= "index($event)">

 <li  *cdkVirtualFor="let item of infinite; trackBy: trackByIdx"> 
     {{item.purchase_stock_id}}

 </li>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?